# Invariance of trace

Tags: linear-algebra

Trace is supposedly invariant under a change of basis.  But isn't a change of basis of a matrix obtained by elementary row (and/ or column) operations?

The trace certainly isn't invariant under any arbitrary elementary row operation -- example:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 5\end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 5\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 5\end{pmatrix}$$

The matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 5\end{pmatrix}$ has trace 6 and the matrix obtained by an elementary row operation $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 5\end{pmatrix}$ has trace 7.

So how is trace invariant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that elementary row operations does not produce a matrix for the same linear operator with respect to a different basis. If $A$ is a matrix for some linear operator, then the matrices of the same operator with respect to different basis are the matrices $B^{-1}AB$, where $B$ is an invertible matrix.

Comment: Then what do elementary row operations do?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to answer that question. Could you specify a little more?

Comment: Matrices represent linear transformations with respect to some basis.  Apparently you change the basis of the linear transformation by the matrix multiplication $B^{-1}AB$ (per your answer).  I thought that's what elementary row operations did, but if not, then if $E$ is an elementary row operation, how does the linear transformation represented by $EA$ relate to the one represented by $A$?  Is there some nice correspondence or do we just use ERO's because they help with Gaussian elimination?

Comment: @user197220 It's taking an input in one basis and giving an output with respect to a different basis.  Only the similarity transformation $B^{-1} AB$ gives you input and output in the same basis always.

Comment: @Muphrid OK, Thanks.  From the answers from you, Mark, and Omnomnomnom, I think I understand this now. :)

Answer (score 2):

Row-operations give you another matrix with the same row-space and the same null-space.  Besides that, there is nothing generally in common between a matrix and a new matrix attained through row-operations.

As an example: a matrix is invertible if and only if it can be brought to the identity matrix via row-operations.  However, the only matrix similar to the identity matrix is the identity matrix itself.